# .NET Core runtime error: LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have encountered this issue a lot recently. I have also found several posts on Stack Overflow about it, but none really managed to answer the root question of what is causing this error and how to fix it.

It's quite frustrating. I create a LINQ query in Visual Studio. It works perfectly when I test it in LINQ Pad. It compiles with no errors. But during runtime, it crashes with the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression [...] could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

The error indicates that you can solve the issue by using `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` when performing your query.
The problem is, *almost every LINQ Query I build uses* `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()`!

I know there are performance concerns regarding client evaluation. But performing complex queries with multiple layers of logic spanning several database tables is what LINQ is best at. Crashing for a reason that doesn't explain the problem makes development of complex systems that much harder.

Has anyone else found this to be a recurring problem? Does anyone know what the cause is and what, if anything, the solution is?

Or am I just missing something?

Here is my issue that I had with this: [.NET Core 3.1 LINQ expression from could not be translated for lists within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66808898/net-core-3-1-linq-expression-from-could-not-be-translated-for-lists-within-a-li)

Comment: Can you share the linq expression? 

Also keep in mind.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: This issue typically is caused when you are using complex types like anonymous objects as a query can not be generated on this

Comment: Linq expression shared via the link at the bottom

Comment: There is no way to select a list of results in a list of result in relational databases (none that I know of anyways). Query both independently then join them locally from  memory. aka there is no group join for entity framework, and this would itself require storing things in a cte table for performance in a sql query.. which I doubt the entity framework team wants to do

Answer (score 0):

There is no group join in entity framework as this is something that just has no 1 to 1 equivalent in sql. You have a couple options here you could select results with group by then join the same table on the results.. or we could use a little memory to do some work wrote this off the cuff so difficult to say if it will run as is but something like this

---

```
var posts =
  (await (from x in _context.UserPosting
          where PostedByList.Contains(x.Posting.PostingId)
          && x.Approved == "A"
          && x.User.Active == true
          select new
          {
              FirstName = x.User.FirstName,
              LastName = x.User.LastName,
              UserEmail = x.User.UserId,
          }).ToListAsync()) // Force enumeration.. aka run query
  // Group here once results are in memory
  .GroupBy( e => new { FirstName = e.User.FirstName, LastName = x.User.LastName, UserId = x.User.UserId }, 
    new { FirstName = e.User.FirstName, LastName = x.User.LastName, UserId = x.User.UserId })
  .Select(e => new UserPostDTO
  {
    FirstName = e.Key.FirstName,
    LastName = e.Key.LastName,
    UserId = e.Key.UserId,
    PostsByUser = e.ToList()
  });
```